# how to make call to 2 numbers depending om the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, native

sorry for all the questions im new to iOS but im wondering is it possible to set a time frame in iOS for example if user push button call me between the time 6am - 6pm the dialer opens and makes the phone call to a nr 567895432 but if it is after hours for example between 6,01pm - 7,59am 
if button call me pushed the user would call 89780324, I know this is possible on php if I should create a Webview app but this is a native app and I don't really want to access a data base just a simple 2way app that sends requests, 
thank you in advance

Comment: sorry I meant 6;01pm - 5;59am

Comment: no you cant with default dialer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it correctly,On button tap, you want to call two different numbers based on time.
Why don't you check on button press

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
NSInteger currentMinute = [components minute];
NSInteger currentSecond = [components second];

    if ((currentHour > 6) && (currentHour < 18)) {
        call 567895432
    }
    else{
        call 89780324
    }
```

Comment: hey bro sorry from heart for arguement... &  thank correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0

```
var components: DateComponents? = 

Calendar.current.dateComponents(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit, from: Date())
var currentHour: Int? = components?.hour
var currentMinute: Int? = components?.minute
var currentSecond: Int? = components?.second
if (currentHour > 6) && (currentHour < 18) {
    call
    567895432
}
else {
    call
    89780324
}
```